# Wait for function 2 to execute inside function 1 - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, promise, wait

Basically i have switch cases. Inside it i will have to execute functions which completely depend on the other functions to execute.

```
Switch(){
    case '1':
        //Executes first always
        function a(){
            ..
            ..
            ..
            b().then(){
                //Execute this block only after function b is executed
            }
            ..
            ..
            .. 
            c().then(){
                //Execute this block only after function c is executed
            }
            ..
            ..
        }
    break;
    case '2':
        function b(){

        }
    break;
    case '3':
        function c(){

        }
    break;
}
```

On above example always, `case '1'` will be executed first. Inside it, i will have to wait for `function b()` to execute and then continue executing
the function a(). like wise for `function c()`. How to achieive this?

Comment: `Switch(){` is incorrect syntax, and just declaring a function won't invoke it - to invoke a function, put `()`s after its name, eg `a();`

Comment: @CertainPerformance would be a typo for explanation. I have functions inside switch statements.

Comment: Does `b` return a promise? If it does not you can't use `then()`, you just need to put code in correct order and they will execute as you wish.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would work... what do you want these functions to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain your promises in order to force sequencing.   Your pseudo-code is a bit confusing.  In addition to the capitalization on `switch(val)`, you're also declaring a function `a()`, but not calling it.  Anyway, if you were going to call `a()` and want to sequence promise returning `b()` and `c()` inside it, you can do this:

```
case '1':
    ..
    a();    // not asynchronous
    ..
    return b().then(c).then(...)
}
```

This assumes that `a()` is not asynchronous and that `b()` and `c()` return promises that are fulfilled when the async operations in them are complete.  And, that there are no other async operations in `a()`.

This will run `c()` when the promise returned by `b()` resolves and then will call the last `.then()` handler when the promise returned by `c()` resolves.

I show a `return` of the promise chain here so the caller could know when all these async operations are done.

If you want code after the switch statement to also wait for these to be done and thus aren't using a `return`, then you would need to switch to using `await` to wait for the promises.

```
async function someFunc() {
    switch(someVal) {
        case '1':
            //Executes first always
            a();    // not asynchronous
            ..
            ..
            ..
            await b();
            //Execute this block only after function b is executed
            ..
            ..
            .. 
            await c()
            //Execute this block only after function c is executed
            ..
            ..
        break;
    }
}
```